# Saving a element from one document to user document

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have those two entites:

```
@Document
public class User {
@Id
private String id;
@Indexed(unique = true)
@NonNull
private String username;
@Indexed(unique = true)
@NonNull
private String email;
@JsonIgnore
@NonNull
private String password;
```

---

```
@Document("adventureholidays")
public class AdventureHolidays {

@Id
private String id;
private String title;
private String description;
private String state;
private String typeOfAdventureHolidays;
private String image;
```

I want to create a service that will save into user document element from adventureholidays.

I have a service to return a random element from adventureholidays document, so If user want to save that document I would like to save title of that document into user document.

So somehow I need to take a ID of current  adventureholiday that is provided and then to save to current logged user.

Answer (score 0):

I am just giving you the logic, add

```
  @DBRef
  private AdventureHolidays adventureHolidays;
```

in your User class it will map both classes, then get the id of holiday from the save button using link or value from your form and then using that id in  `find()` function and  fetch the data of that particular holiday store it in a object ie. holiday.

Now just save it in service class inside a method like this:

```
User user=new User();
user.setAdventureHolidays(holiday);

// create a userRepository which extends MongoRepository

userRepository.save(user);
```